# Select menu behaving strangely with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown whose options get filled dynamically:

```
function populateDropdown(dropdownNum) {
// invokeWebService uses $.ajax
json = invokeWebService("GET", "/webservice/dropwdownOptions");
optionsHtml = "";

$.each(json, function(count, jsObj) {
             optionValue = jsObj.name
             optionsHtml+="<option>" + optionValue + "</option>";
             });

var dropdownId = "#NRdropdown_" + dropdownNum;
$(dropdownId).html(optionsHtml);
}

function display(blockNum) {
var url = "/webservice/blocks" + blockNum;
var response = invokeWebService("GET", url);

var replacementHtml = "";
var currBlock = "blah";

$.each(response, function(i, block) {
                 currName = block.name;
                 var textfield = "<input type='text' id='blockValue" + block.id +
                                 "'>";
                 var dropdownMenu = "<select id=\"NRdropdown_" + i + 
                                    "\"onClick=\"populateDropDown(" + i +
                                    ")\"><option>Existing Blocks</option>"

                 var submitButton = "<input type='submit' value='UPDATE' id='" +
                                    block.id + "'><br><br>";

                 replacementHtml = currName + textfield + dropdownMenu + submitButton;
                 });
$("#main").html(replacementHtml);
}
```

The javascript function "populateDropdown(dropdownNum)":

1. Makes the ajax request
2. Parses the json response for the option values into an html string called optionsHtml
3. Replaces the inner html of the select element with the option values via:

   ```
   var dropdownSelector = "#NRdropdown_" + dropdownNum;
   $(dropdownSelector).html(optionsHtml)
   ```

1) When I click on the dropdown arrow, I STILL see "Existing Blocks".
2) After 1 sec I see the first dynamically generated option UNDERNEATH the "Existing Blocks" option, I don't see the other dynamically generated options. 
3) Then I click outside the dropdown and see the dropdwon showing the first dynamically generated value.
4) Finally I click the dropdown arrow again and it works as it should with all the dynamically generated values.

How do I make it work so that:

1. When the page first loads, the dropdown shows "Existing Blocks".
2. Once I click the dropdown arrow, the dropdown should show all dynamically generated values without the "Existing Blocks" value.

Thanks!

Comment: First, make sure you are closing your <select>. Secondly, are you generating these dropdowns in a for loop?

Comment: Yes, I am closing the select tag in my code but forgot to add it in my post.  I am generating these dropdowns in a for loop because(this is unrelated to my question) but I have multiple rows where each row consists of my dropdown followed by a textfield.  These rows are generated by a for loop, and each dropdown's options are filled in with a for loop too.

Comment: Can you show that for loop also?

Comment: I have added the complete code bagonyi

Answer (score 0):

the dropdown listener should be for onmousedown, not onclick